# trying to figure out the Layout Update XML

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I am using magento 1.9.2.4, I am trying to edit the home page and update the homepage, had to add parallax video but when I open the homepage, its content was empty and design tab had this. I can't find these static blocks in the admin panel. Could someone let me know how to find these and if I have to add the parallax video, how do I add it in the same manner?

```
<reference name="pt_home_deals">
<block type="carousel/carousel" name="home.deals">
    <action method="setBlockTitle"><string>Daily Deal</string></action>
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>pt/carousel/default_deals.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="setConfig">
        <values>
            <data_source>catalog_category</data_source>
                            <block_des>wysiwyg/icon-deals.jpg</block_des>
                            <is_special_filter>1</is_special_filter>
                            <product_count>6</product_count>
                            <order_by>top_views</order_by>
            <col_xs>1</col_xs>
            <col_sm>2</col_sm>
            <col_md>2</col_md>
            <col_lg>3</col_lg>
        </values>
    </action>
</block>
```

```
<reference name="pt_home_slider">
<block type="slider/slider" name="home.slider">
 <action method="setTemplate"><path>pt/slider/default.phtml</path></action>
 <action method="setGroupId"><group_id>1</group_id></action>
 </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to make sure that you are looking at the right page that you are trying to edit. To check which page is being used for the homepage look in `system-> config-> general-> web-> default pages`. You will see something like pictured:

[image]

From there you can track down the correct cms page `cms-> pages` to find something like this:

[image]

The link being "Madison Island" for the home page i have set up.

It looks in your case that you are using a custom theme for your site. That is declared in `system-> config-> general-> design`. From here you can see what theme is being used.

To get your content in, you have a few different options. If you are willing to edit the theme itself you can just place your code in the template file that is being used on the homepage.

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>pt/carousel/default_deals.phtml</template></action>
```

You can find this file at `app/design/frontend/{package_name}/{theme_name}/template/pt/carousel/default_deals.phtml`.

The other idea (depending on your set up) would be to use `local.xml` to place your block in the page with xml. This would be best if you have a custom theme that you created and want to keep all your overrides local to that theme.

```
<cms_index_index>
<block type="core/template" name="your_custom_file" as="your_custom_file" template="path/to_your/custom.phtml" before="-"/>
</cms_index_index>
```

Of course there are a lot of other ways to do this, but these are some common ways that you can try.